# Extracting segment path parameters from url

Tags: c#

I have been trying to figure out how I could extract the segment path parameters from a REST url.
We know that REST url parameters can be represented in two ways:

1. As part of the path
2. As a query parameter.

When a user clicks on a link from our website we capture the link and the subsequent path traversed using Google Api and save it in our database as three parts:

1. The base url
2. The segment path parameters (if any)
3. The query parameters (if any).

For example: `http://www.test.com/article/12345?order=2`

is seperated into:

baseurl : `http://www.test.com/article`
segment path parameters : `12345`
query parameters : `order=2`

I am aware of how I can separate the segments out of a url, but my question is how do I know if in a given url a segment is a parameter or not. For example in the above example "12345" could be a REST parameter or simply part of the path. How does one distinguish that

Comment: isn't that already determined by the WCF Operation Uri Template?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"http://www.test.com/article/12345?order=2");

foreach (var segment in uri.Segments)
{
    Console.WriteLine(segment);
}
```

and you will get:

```
/
article/
12345
```

`uri.Query` would give you `?order=2`

Comment: I have rephrased the question.